# What's the best description for this game-piece placement?

Tags: phrase-requests

I have a game in which pieces normally get tiled in an arrangement like this (which can be shortened or extended arbitrarily):

[image: Figure placement without solo]

But in special circumstances a piece may be permitted to be placed in between and on top of the other pieces, like this (red circle shows the one piece placed on the corner of four other pieces):

[image: Figure placement with solo]

I'd like to briefly describe this placement something like this:

> A red piece may be placed _____ in relation to normal pieces.

What the best, short, clear way to describe this placement?

Comment: You could look at descriptions of [roulette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette) which includes similar arrangements; but I'm not seeing anything very notable, just variations of "on the corner..."

Comment: By "best" do you mean "easiest to understand, likely to be understood by most people"?

Comment: Is the grid the playing board? Must 4 rather than say 1 or 3 pieces be covered in such a move?

Comment: In order for the piece shown in red to be placed on the board between (on top of?) other pieces, do all of the four squares have to be occupied by a piece? Or can a piece be placed on top of four squares at any time?

Comment: It's not clear whether we're talking about a game like dominoes where the pieces are rectangles and played on a plain table, or if we have a matrix board on which circular pieces are played. I think it's the former.

Comment: @Tim By "best" I mean a combination of short, idiomatic, easiest to understand.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The grid isn't the playing board, it's tiled playing pieces. Each square-with-circle indicates a tiled playing piece.

Comment: @Tim: More like dominoes; the pieces have square bases with a raised figure in the middle. For practical purposes, you need four pieces together to place another piece on top; otherwise the special piece will likely tilt and and fall off.

Comment: Is the piece that sits on top of four tiles the same size as those four? Does the piece on top rest on the raised cylinders of the tiles below it?  Could you say "A piece can be placed upon existing pieces if it will be touching four circles"?

Comment: A red piece may *straddle* four squares.

Comment: @AntonSherwood   *Straddle* is good but it might have to be changed to "*must* straddle" if it is a prerequisite.

Comment: @AntonSherwood: That's good, I'd upvote (maybe select) that if you made it an answer?

Comment: @Tim: There's some variation, so what I'm indicating in red may be the same size or smaller than other pieces (so they may or may not exactly touch in this position). They can't rest on top of the cylindrical figures (compare to chess pieces with square bases, perhaps).

Answer (score 2):

This red piece **straddles** the four squares.  Wiktionary:

> (transitive) To sit or stand with a leg on each side of something; to sit astride.
> (transitive) To be on both sides of something; to have parts that are in different places, regions, etc.

Literally the red piece straddles the *boundary* but I think this specialized extension is natural.

(Does this game also have circumstances in which it can straddle two?)

Answer (score 2):

## Intersection

A red piece may be placed at the *intersection* of four squares, instead of *inside* a square.

Answer (score 0):

"A red piece may be placed on the point where the corners of four normal pieces meet."

"A red piece may be placed at the intersection of four normal pieces."

A picture is worth 1000 words in this instance :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

> A red piece may be ***centrally*** placed ***between*** four normal pieces *(at a symmetrical distance from each of them)*.

Answer (score 0):

You could also say:

A red dot can be placed on the board so it's **touching** four squares.

Comment: That's not enough to clearly convey the position. If I heard this, I would put the red dot on a white dot so it's orthogonally surrounded by 4 other squares (the same way a [chess piece on white](https://overboardblog.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/orthgrid.gif) is orthographically surrounded by 4 black squares).

Comment: OK, I'll edit in case the game is going to have more than two rows.  I took "shortened or extended" to refer to columns.

Comment: I say that because OP says "on top of other pieces"